# Async method sometimes never ends

Tags: c#, task, .net-4.5, async-await

I am taking  images and processing them.
Then I am trying to save bitmaps(these images) in a file.

For example

- I take "desert" and "flower" images and I process them 4 times each one asynchronously.
- Then I call(await) 8 times saveAsync() method to save them.

  - What happens is desert_modified and flower_modified, flower_modified(1), flower_modified(2), flower_modified(3) are saved.
  - There are no images desert_modified(1), desert_modified(2), desert_modified(3).

The methods that are going to save them never finishes. Any suggestion?

```
async private Task saveAsync(Bitmap bitmap, String path, String fileName, int requestNo)
{
    int temp = 1;
    String pth = path;
    String fileName1 = fileName;
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                if (File.Exists(pth))
                {

                    String[] array = fileName1.Split('.');
                    String modifiedFileName = array[0] + "_modified" + "(" + temp + ")." + array[1];
                    pth = fullPath.Replace(fileName1, modifiedFileName);

                    while (File.Exists(pth))
                    {
                        temp++;
                        //array = fileName.Split('.');
                        modifiedFileName = array[0] + "_modified" + "(" + temp + ")." + array[1];
                        pth = fullPath.Replace(fileName1, modifiedFileName);

                    }

                    bitmap.Save(@pth);

                }
                else
                {
                    bitmap.Save(@pth);
                }
                bitmap.Dispose();
            });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        outputTextBox2.Text += ex.InnerException.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies.. I just realised I was incorrect. Coffee time!

Comment: Have a look at System.IO.FileInfo by the way. It will give you betters ways to modify the filename

Comment: I added an answer showing just what I meant. I have used IO.Path instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're interested in improving the code as I hinted in my comment, here's a start:

As you can see, this

- removes the (confusingly named) local variables like `pth`, `fileName1` and `modifiedFileName`
- No longer *abuses* `Split` to (erronously) dissect the path (what if a directory had an extension? What if a filename contains `.` itself?)
- uses `PathCombine` to get the proper path separator
- uses a fixed format string to easily generate candidate filenames
- uses a single `do-while` loop instead of duplicating the lines generating a filename

Overall, I think it's a *lot* simpler.

```
await Task.Run(() =>
  {
      var fmt = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)) + "_modified{0}" + Path.GetExtension(fileName);

      int counter = 1;
      string newName;
      do {
          newName = string.Format(fmt, counter++);
      }
      while (File.Exists(newName));

      using (bitmap)
          bitmap.Save(newName);
  });
```

I made it into a simple standalone test program on my local PC so I could actually test it:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

public class X
{
    public class Bitmap : IDisposable { 
        public void Dispose() { } 
        public void Save(string location)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Saving: {0}", location);
            using (var s = new StreamWriter(location))
                s.WriteLine("hello world");
        }
    }

    private static void saveAsync(Bitmap bitmap, String path, String fileName, int requestNo)
    {
        Action a = () =>
          {
              var fmt = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)) + "_modified{0}" + Path.GetExtension(fileName);

              int counter = 1;
              string newName;
              do {
                  newName = string.Format(fmt, counter++);
              }
              while (File.Exists(newName));

              using (bitmap)
                  bitmap.Save(newName);
          };

        a();
        a();
        a();
        a();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        saveAsync(new Bitmap(), "/tmp", "foo.png", 3);
    }
}
```

This prints

```
Saving: /tmp/foo_modified1.png
Saving: /tmp/foo_modified2.png
Saving: /tmp/foo_modified3.png
Saving: /tmp/foo_modified4.png
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Since I am new to c# your answer is very inductive for me.

Answer (score 2):

You use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fk49wtc1.aspx), which is actually not appropriate here.
I think the main mistake in your code is that you're trying to replace `fileName1` in `pth` within the while loop, *although* fileName1 does *not* appear in `pth` because it was modified before the while loop. **Thus**, `pth` is never changed within the while loop, which is the reason for the while loop never ending.

To fix this, either use `pth = fullPath.Replace(pth, modifiedFileName)` **OR**, what I would recommend: `pth = modifiedFileName`.

Anyway, you don't save any memory by using `Replace`, since Strings in C#, as well as in many other languages, are immutable! So even by `Replace`, a new String is generated.

*EDIT:* ... Hmm.. maybe this answer isn't fully correct, since you're working on `fullPath` *BUT* on the other hand, `fullPath` isn't defined in this function :) .. where does this even come from?

Comment: I had the same problem with `fullPath`. I assumed that it was somehow a class member or a copy/paste artefact from having to many modifications to this code (trying to get it to work)? Anyways, I have [done a code-review style refactoring](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18138628/85371), assuming that the full path should be combined from `path` and `fileName` (still ignoring `requestNo` for now)